# What does 'bower update' do on a private git repo?

Tags: bower

When I issue 'bower update' on a private git repo that I use as a dependency, how does bower decide whether it's time to update?
One thing I noticed is that it doesn't look into the package version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks at [semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver) valid git tags or falls back to the latest commit.